# MVC desktop - onde está o Controller?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, swing, mvc, controller

Modifiquei [este exemplo de MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/2241463) para tentar tornar mais parecido com a minha visão de MVC (na qual o papel do Controller não está muito claro). Terminei com um programa que só possui Views e Model, sem Controller. Onde deveria estar o Controller?

Uma coisa que me surpreendeu foi ter criado um comportamento de observar o estado da view. Minha ideia era que haveria apenas observação do estado do Model, aí eu percebi que precisava implementar observação de estado da view (método `OneOfTheViews.update()`). É esperado que haja esse comportamento no MVC?

Outra coisa relativamente inesperada foi que as views estão aninhadas, isto é, há uma `MainPanel` que é mãe de outras views. Não sei se isso está certo no MVC ou não.

P.S.: Ficou ajeitadinho o programa assim com as classes curtinhas, não? Ponto para o MVC :D

[image: MVC Game]

#### MvcGame.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.view.MainPanel;

public class MvcGame implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Componentes Swing devem ser construídos no EDT (event-dispatching thread).
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new MvcGame());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new MainPanel().asComponent());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

#### Piece.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.model;

import java.awt.Color;

public enum Piece {
    RED(Color.red),
    GREEN(Color.green),
    BLUE(Color.blue);

    private final Color color;

    private Piece(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

#### Model.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.model;

import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Model
 */
public class Model extends Observable {

    private static final Random RAND_NUM_GEN = new Random();
    private Piece hidden = init();

    private Piece init() {
        Piece[] pieces = Piece.values();
        return pieces[RAND_NUM_GEN.nextInt(pieces.length)];
    }

    public void reset() {
        hidden = init();
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void check(Piece guess) {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(guess.equals(hidden));
    }
}
```

#### MainPanel.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.model.Model;

public final class MainPanel {

    private final JPanel mainPanel; 

    public MainPanel() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        Model model = new Model();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Guess what color!", JLabel.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        OneOfTheViews view = new OneOfTheViews(model);
        mainPanel.add(view.asComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        ControlPanel controlPanel = new ControlPanel(model);
        mainPanel.add(controlPanel.asComponent(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public JPanel asComponent() {
        return mainPanel;
    }
}
```

#### OneOfTheViews.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.model.Model;
import piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.model.Piece;

/**
 * View
 */
public class OneOfTheViews {

    private static final String TEXT_CLICK_A_BUTTON = "Click a button.";

    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private final ColorRoundIcon icon = new ColorRoundIcon(80, Color.gray);
    private final JLabel labelMoveOutcome = initLabel(); 
    private final Model model;

    public OneOfTheViews(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
        model.addObserver(new ModelObserver());
        panel.add(labelMoveOutcome, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(genButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public JPanel asComponent() {
        return panel;
    }

    private JLabel initLabel() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(TEXT_CLICK_A_BUTTON, icon, JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        return label;
    }

    private JPanel genButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        for (Piece piece : Piece.values()) {
            PieceButton pieceButton = new PieceButton(piece, this);
            panel.add(pieceButton.asComponent());
        }

        return panel;
    }

    public void update(Piece piece) {
        icon.setColor(piece.getColor());
        labelMoveOutcome.repaint();
        model.check(piece);
    }

    private class ModelObserver implements Observer {

        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            if (arg == null) {
                labelMoveOutcome.setText(TEXT_CLICK_A_BUTTON);
                icon.setColor(Color.gray);
            } else if ((Boolean) arg) {
                labelMoveOutcome.setText("Win!");
            } else {
                labelMoveOutcome.setText("Keep trying.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### ControlPanel.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.view;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.model.Model;

/**
 * Control panel
 */
public class ControlPanel {

    private static final String RESET_LABEL = "Reset";

    private final Model model;
    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private final JButton resetButton = new JButton(RESET_LABEL);

    public ControlPanel(Model model) {
        this.model = model;

        panel.add(resetButton);
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ResetButtonHandler());
    }

    public JPanel asComponent() {
        return panel;
    }

    private class ResetButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
            if (RESET_LABEL.equals(cmd)) {
                model.reset();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### ColorRoundIcon.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.swing.Icon;

public final class ColorRoundIcon implements Icon {

    private final int size;
    private Color color;

    public ColorRoundIcon(int size, Color color) {
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, size, size);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = Objects.requireNonNull(color);
    }
}
```

#### PieceButton.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.view;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.model.Piece;

public final class PieceButton {

    private final JButton pieceButton;
    private final Piece piece;
    private final OneOfTheViews view;

    public PieceButton(Piece piece, OneOfTheViews view) {
        this.piece = piece;
        this.view = view;
        this.pieceButton = new JButton(new ColorRoundIcon(16, piece.getColor()));
        this.pieceButton.addActionListener(new PieceButtonHandler());
    }

    public Piece getPiece() {
        return piece;
    }

    public JButton asComponent() {
        return pieceButton;
    }

    private class PieceButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            view.update(piece);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O papel do Controller é receber os *inputs* do usuário a partir da View, validar os dados se for o caso e passar para o Model. Em seguida, notificar a View de mudanças no Model, se o Model já não tiver um mecanismo de Observer para fazer isso (como é feito na pergunta).

No exemplo da pergunta o que está faltando é um Controller para intermediar a entrada do usuário (pressionamento de botão) de determinada View que leve à chamada de um método desse Controller em vez de chamar diretamente o método `model.reset()`, por exemplo. Portanto adicionando um Controller ficaria algo assim:

```
public class ControlPanel {

    (...)

    private class ResetButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
            if (RESET_LABEL.equals(cmd)) {
                controller.reset();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O controller (simples até demais) seria:

#### Controller.java

```
package piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.controller;

import java.util.Objects;

import piovezan.mvcdesktop_trashgod.model.Model;

public class ControlPanelController {

    private final Model model;
    
    public ControlPanelController(Model model) {
        this.model = Objects.requireNonNull(model);
    }
    
    public void reset() {
        model.reset();
    }
}
```

Estou assumindo a premissa de que o número de Controllers é um por View.

Answer (score -1):

Eu vou tentar explicar o pouco que conheço sobre MVC. O MVC é um padrão de arquitetura de software, que separa a aplicação na MODEL (responsável pela manipulação dos dados), VIEW (responsável pela interação do usuário) e CONTROLLER (responsável por receber as requisições do usuário enviar para o MODEL e retransmitir para a VIEW ou seja o gerenciador).
Visualizando seu projeto (a imagem dá para identificar o controller como os botões vermelho, verde, azul e reset), nestes botões ficam as requisições que serão enviadas para o MODEL. O MODEL analisa e retorna o que foi solicitado (dentro das condições).

Obs.: uma boa pratica seria não deixar implementações nas classes model, para isso costumo implementar uma camada a mais entre o model e o controller, neste caso é uma camada SERVICE(utilizado para guardar e fazer a validação das regras de negócio, removendo as regras tanto do controller quanto do model).

Espero ter ajudado um pouco!

Comment: Sua resposta fugiu do assunto. O OP queria saber onde está o controller e você simplesmente tentou explicar o que é o MVC. Não ajudou muito.